# Exporting multiple sheets to multiple PDF's and adding in Sendmail as attachment with HTML body

Tags: google-apps-script

i've looked and tried many solutions but for some reason I can't get it to work.

My goal:

- Automaticly sending e-mails on time trigger (works)
- Based on cell value (works)
- With HTML mail format (google form) (works)
- With 2 or more attachments (doesn't work)

How can I change the code so it'll include 2 pdf files? It can be one of the two options:
1. Grab pdf grom google drive folder by name, where I got a working function to export 2 or more sheets to pdf - using the same name (and removing older version).
2. Convert 2 or more sheets to corresponding PDF files and add them as attachment.

I'm rather new, so still trying to figure my way around.

Tried combinding Several solutions found here but I either keep getting 'file iteration' error.

When using variant of GetFilesByName, if(file.HasNext(), getAs('application/PDF'), I get no error but no mail is sent either.

```
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getRange(1,5).getValue(); // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, 15, 3); // this function is: Row, Column, Number of Rows, Number of Columns
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
 // var bijlage1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('EDC-A.pdf'); // definiëring van file 2
 // var bijlage2 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('EDC-B.pdf'); // definiëring van file 1
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var body = '';
    var html =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('body').evaluate().getContent(); // legt link met Body html file
    var options = {
      htmlBody: html 
    };
    var aantaluzk = row[2]; // Third column
    if (aantaluzk != 0) { // Variable
      var subject = 'Uitzendkrachten te evalueren';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,body,options);                
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // geen idee wat dit doet?
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT: as by request, 
Code containing the script for export (was in different script file)**
µ
Based on comments so far, I've managed to  make it work through:
- Combine the pdf export script with the Sendmail function and defining them as variables. Don't understand fully how it works with blob, but it does.
- Repeat the export script for each sheet, changing the required parameters.

Resulting in a script that works but most likely could be made much simpler?

**Final result**

```
// Test en goedgekeurd 19/6
function MailExport() {
  var sheetName = "EDCA";
  var folderID = "1gNoRIktbqYjIzE8txUezW5wt_jliIWYJ"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
  var pdfName = "EDC-A"; // "+Date()" toevoegen zonder "" indien timestamp aan file toegevoegd;

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

  // Vernietig de vorige versie
  DriveApp.getFilesByName('EDC-A').next().setTrashed(true);  

  //Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  //delete redundant sheets
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  //repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

  //save to pdf
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

  // Afdeling 2

  var sheetName = "EDCB";
  var folderID = "1gNoRIktbqYjIzE8txUezW5wt_jliIWYJ"; // Folder id to save in a folder.
  var pdfName = "EDC-B"; // "+Date()" toevoegen zonder "" indien timestamp aan file toegevoegd;

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);

  // Vernietig de vorige versie
  DriveApp.getFilesByName('EDC-B').next().setTrashed(true);  

  //Copy whole spreadsheet
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  //delete redundant sheets
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  //repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references) 
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

  //save to pdf
  var theBlob2 = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile2 = folder.createFile(theBlob2);

  //Delete the temporary sheet
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);

  // Onderdeel voor mail

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getRange(1,5).getValue(); // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, 15, 3); // this function is: Row, Column, Number of Rows, Number of Columns
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var body = '';
    var html =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('body').evaluate().getContent(); // legt link met Body html file
    var options = {
      attachments: [theBlob,theBlob2],
      htmlBody: html
    };
    var aantaluzk = row[2]; // Third column
    if (aantaluzk != 0) { // Variable
      var subject = 'Uitzendkrachten te evalueren';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,body,options);                
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // geen idee wat dit doet?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the part of your script that is exporting the sheet to pdf?

Comment: Edited post to add this part. It was in a different script file, as I couldn't get them working together. Managed to do so now, but probably not the most efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to include the attachments into your email, you have to insert them in “Options” with the syntax as [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)):

```
attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
```

So you can either include a pdf file directly as an attachment, or convert with

```
file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)
```

a file of another format to pdf. I suggest you to implement the desired files into your code with their ID (since the name can be ambiguous) with the function:

```
DriveApp.getFileById()
```

To summarize, your code should look like this:

```
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getRange(1,5).getValue(); // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, 15, 3); // this function is: Row, Column, Number of Rows, Number of Columns
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var bijlage1 = DriveApp.getFileById(IDofPDFfile); // definiëring van file 2
  var bijlage2 = DriveApp.getFileById(IDofNonPDFFile'); // definiëring van file 1
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var body = '';
        var options = {
       name: 'this is optional',
   //in this example bijlage1 is a pdf already, while bijlage2 has to be converted to a pdf first:
       attachments: [bijlage1, bijlage2.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
        }

    var aantaluzk = row[2]; 
// Third column
    if (aantaluzk != 0) { // Variable
      var subject = 'Uitzendkrachten te evalueren';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,body,options);                
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // geen idee wat dit doet?
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, cleared up some parts and started messing around more. Edited original post with complete code which I got working for now but definitly isn't the most efficient.

Questions:
- How to find the ID of a pdf file? Can't grab it from the URL as opening the pdf never shows the ID in the URL (only folder url).
- In this case, the pdf needs to be overwritten weekly (by the other script, or combined in this one). I'm guessing the ID changes here aswell, so i'm stuck with getting it by name?

Comment: 1. : The sheet ID is contained among others between the ** https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/** and the **/edit#gid=0** part of the URL:
**https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/THIS_IS_THE_SHEET_ID/edit#gid=0**

Comment: 2.: Accessing the file by name returns, as the function name `getFilesByName` suggests, an array of potentially multiple entries ( Drive supports storing various files with the same name). You can make it work like this:
`var names= DriveApp.getFilesByName(('EDC-A.pdf')
  while (names.hasNext()) 
  {
    var bijlage1=(names.next())
    }` to get 1 file back.
However, if you have several files with the same name, you should assign the return values of `getFilesByName` to an array and implement additional criteria to decide which file to select (e.g. the one with the newest creation date).